# Django grouped queryset with subqueries

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a grouped queryset in Django to first group by `occupation` and then aggregate sum of `occupation` by `date_rented` where `date_rented` is grouped by month.

I have been able to accomplish getting the desired results in python but it seems rather inefficient to me as it is necessary to do subqueries for each `occupation` to get the sum according to `date_rented`. Failing being able to use Django's built-in query API, I suppose I will have no choice but to use this solution, but if anyone can help me solve this using Django built in query API, I will be eternally grateful.

**Model**

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=254)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    date_rented = models.DateField()
```

**Sample Data**

```
| id | name              | occupation         | date_rented   |
| -- | ----------------- | ------------------ | ------------- |
| 1  | Orlando Barrero   | Electrician        | 2020-01-13    |
| 2  | Miguel Espinosa   | Mechanic           | 2020-01-24    |
| 3  | Renan Figueroa    | Electrician        | 2020-02-22    |
| 4  | Marco Galvez      | Mechanic           | 2020-03-13    |
| 5  | Eric Mendosa      | Mechanic           | 2020-03-22    |
| 6  | Giovani Vela      | Electrician        | 2020-03-24    |
```

**Expected Result**

```
| occupation         | January | February | March |
| ------------------ | ------- | -------- | ----- |
| Electrician        | 1       | 1        | 1     |
| Mechanic           | 1       | 0        | 2     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the elements per occupation and per month with:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Tenant.objects.values(
    'occupation',
    month=TruncMonth('date_rented')
).annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('occupation', 'month')
```

This will return a queryset:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'occupation': 'Electrician', 'month': date(2020, 1, 1), 'count': 1},
    {'occupation': 'Electrician', 'month': date(2020, 2, 1), 'count': 1},
    {'occupation': 'Electrician', 'month': date(2020, 3, 1), 'count': 1},
    {'occupation': 'Mechanic', 'month': date(2020, 1, 1), 'count': 1},
    {'occupation': 'Mechanic', 'month': date(2020, 3, 1), 'count': 2},
]>
```

You will still have to post-process the data however. Furhtermore combinations of months/occupations for which there are no `Tenant` objects will *not* be listed in the queryset, for example `Mechanic`/February is here *not* present.